# How to fit hdodenhof circleimageview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using hdodenhof.circleimageview lib,

I am getting image like this - [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h86fE.png)

How can i fit the image into this, without stretching image outside

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_edit_category"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:contextClickable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView

        android:id="@+id/edit_category_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/transport"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        app:civ_border_overlay="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/colorLightGrey"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorGrey"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edit_category_text"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit_category_image"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxLength="16"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is it possible to decrease size or something

Answer (score 2):

option 1

```
     val imageLoader: ImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance()
                        val options: DisplayImageOptions = DisplayImageOptions
                            .Builder()
                            .displayer(CircleBitmapDisplayer())
                            .showImageOnLoading(drawable)
                            .showImageOnFail(drawable)
                            .showImageForEmptyUri(drawable)
                            .cacheInMemory(true)
                            .cacheOnDisk(true)
                            .build()

                        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView, options)
```

option 2

```
 Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
    .into(imageView)
```

You can try this with Imageview by setting scaltype in xml without using circle imageview

Answer (score 0):

Add some padding to the image or use an image with 1:1 aspect ratio. This library doesn't support scaleType so you can do it without any 3rd Party library

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/black">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/circular_image"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/your_img" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: is there any way using that lib

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).noFade().transform(CircleTransform()).into(imageView)

public class CircleTransform implements Transformation {
public CircleTransform() { }
@Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

    int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 7;
    int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 7;

    Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
    if (squaredBitmap != source) {
        source.recycle();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
            BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(shader);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    float r = size / 2f;
    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

    squaredBitmap.recycle();
    return bitmap;
}
@Override
public String key() {
    return "circle";
}
```

}